# How to change from a GPG key to a conventional password?

Tags: kwallet

I changed a while ago from a standard password (the same as my login password) to a GPG key that I had to unlock using a password (also the same as my login password) but I now have to type in my password twice. I would like to go back to only typing in my password once. How can I switch back from a GPG key to a password?